# Restore .sql export to WordPress db from within WordPress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I've been developing a client's site and have maintained .sql backups using Export of phpMyAdmin. Yesterday my client provided me with credentials for the destination server and asked if I could migrate the development site to the beta site.

I can copy the files, of course, and I have changed wp-config.php to point to the new database correctly. When I load the page initially a default WordPress installation is created.

Unfortunately, I was not provided cPanel or phpMyAdmin credentials.

Ideally, there would be a plugin or script that would drop all of the existing tables created by default and use my .sql export to recreate the tables and populate them with data.

Does anyone know if there is a way to import this .sql from within WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

You can import it with mysql on the command line:

```
mysql -u someuser -p password <yoursqlfile.sql
```

Or you can open it in mysql workbench (download from mysql.com) and run it from there.

Comment: Sure! I wish I had access to a command line. I think I have only HTTP access to the db using the credentials I've placed in wp-config.php

Answer (score 0):

In case you cannot SSH to the server or access the database via workbench as [Norbert suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29448827/3250005), you can try [XCloner](https://wordpress.org/plugins/xcloner-backup-and-restore/).

It would be better if you had some sort of direct access to the database, but I'm guessing if you do not have cpanel access you also do not have SSH access. It is also common for databases to be restricted to local access, so a remote connection via MySQL Workbench may not be an option.

If for whatever reason none of these solutions work, you can temporarily connect the site to a remote database that you have access to until you get the necessary credentials from the client.

Comment: XCloner looks interesting. This is exactly the type of utility I was hoping for. I am going to find a good stopping point and backup my current work. Then I'll give it a try. Thank you!